# How to hide a popup / div using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup, hide

I am building a settings menu for my site which would appear as a popup. Currently, I can open/close this popup by clicking on the button linked to it.However, I would like to implement a way to close this popup/div by simply clicking outside the popup.

I believe JavaScript can complete this action, unfortunately, I'm am not yet well versed in using this language.

Does anyone have a solution that satisfies my needs, this is what i am working with...

Thanks in advance :)

```js
var settingsmenu = document.querySelector(".settings-menu");

function settingsMenuToggle(){
    settingsmenu.classList.toggle("settings-menu-height");
}
```

```css
.settings-menu{
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 350px;
  background: var(--color-light);
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 84px;
  right: 9%;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height 0.3s;
}

.settings-menu-height{
  max-height: 300px;
}



.settings-menu-inner{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="create">
    <figure onclick="settingsMenuToggle()">
      <button>Open Popup</button>
    </figure>
</div>



<div class="settings-menu">

  <div class="settings-menu-inner">

    <figure>
      <img src="https://images.macrumors.com/t/Y_7ongT7QQ-k0uYwUE4uCoCO3TI=/800x0/article-new/2019/08/apple-settings-icon-19.jpg-250x250.jpg?lossy" width="100" height="100">
      <h3>This is a popup</h3>
    </figure>


   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy, you wrap your current popover in one extra div; so if you currently had:

```
<div class="settings-menu">
  ...stuff...
</div>
```

then you turn that into:

```
<div class="popover-backplate">
  <div class="settings-menu">
    ...stuff...
  </div>
</div>
```

Next you add some CSS like:

```
.popover-backplate {
    position:         fixed;
    width:            100vw;
    height:           100vh;
    background-color: red;
    opacity:          0.5;
}
```

If that worked then there should be a semi-transparent red overlay over the entire page (everything outside the popover anyway). If that is not the case then you may have to add a `z-index` property to both `settings-menu` and/or `popover-backplate`.

Once the visual part works, all that's left is adding a bit of javascript under `popover-backplate`s `onclick`-event, which calls your `popover_close()`-function (whatever it is called).

Comment: The visual part worked perfectly, however, I'm having trouble incorporating the JavaScript to close the popup. Can you please help?

Comment: Sure, but would have to see what the current code looks like. Most likely though, all you need is to grab the outermost container (which is guess would now be `div.popover-backplate`) and remove that from the dom.

Comment: The current code is the opening query I created. I did not go into adding content inside as of yet because I thought it'll be best to tackle this problem while there is very minimal code. The goal is to first work with this empty div; and make sure all of it's interactive related functions work smoothly. @Raxi

Comment: probably something like this should do the trick then: `document.getElementsByClassName('popover-backplate')].map(popup => popup && popup.remove());`

Comment: The idea is you take the outermost container(s) which should include or contain both the overlay (backplate) and the popup itself, and you just remove those items from the dom.

Comment: Some components / properties may be interfering. The popup is not closing after clicking outside the area. Have a look @Raxi : https://jsfiddle.net/jm4pa6dk/

Comment: I see;  I've fixed it up a bit for you, should be fully functional now, and i've added some comments for clarification and stuff : https://pastebin.com/rMWUvTAM

Comment: and i imagine you'll likely end up having like save/cancel buttons inside that popover eventually; when you make those you just put `popover.style.display = 'none';` under both of them, to let them close the popover.

Comment: Just had a chance to review the changes/ adjustments / comments; everything is working great. I will continue to study this solution to gain a greater understanding of how everything is working; I like knowing whats happening to be able to to help others with similar problems and be able to solve them for myself as well.

Thank you for the helping hand @Raxi

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your popup in another element - it's one of the easiest approaches. Let's say, it will have class "tint", and inside it will contain your popup div.
And to catch the event on the background, you can add an event listener to the document, and check the click target every time. If the click target is the background (i.e. our "tint"), we just hide the "tint" element, and the event will not fire again, because it has **once: true.** Otherwise we set the event again.
Of course, it's just a simple snippet for demonstration. You can extend it and modify it to your needs.

```js
function documentLoaded(fn) {
  if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

function popupClickListener(e){
  if (e.target.classList.contains('tint')) {
    document.querySelector('.tint').style.display = 'none';
  } else {
        document.addEventListener('click', popupClickListener, {once: true});
  }
}

documentLoaded(function(){
  document.querySelector('.show-popup').onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector('.tint').style.display = 'block';
    document.addEventListener('click', popupClickListener, {once: true});
  }
});
```

```css
.tint {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: 10000;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #fff;
  width: calc(100% - 20px);
  max-width: 550px;
  min-height: 130px;
  margin: 50px 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0px);
}
```

```html
<div class="tint">
  <div class="popup">popup-content</div>
</div>
<div class="page-content">
  some content<br>
  <button class="show-popup">show popup</button>
</div>
```